# How to make Windows authentication in ASP.NET MVC using LDAPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication

I want to build a web application where a user logs in using his windows account through a login form. In this application I'm gonna have to use LDAPS (and not LDAP). I've been searching on internet for a tutorial to guide me but I found some code snippet on forums of people that are having trouble with their code. I couldn't understand where to put that code or why I should put it especially that I'm very new to ASP.NET.

Could you please provide me with some information or links that can help me ? 
Also should I use ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WEB API?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WEB API: This desition should be not based on if you need to use LDAP or not.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how to use LDAPS with Framework ASP.NET ?

Comment: There is a bunch of good articles if you search it on Google. I think https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ldap-access-control-for-Asp-Net/ is a good one.